# Serial port get memory command

Tags: serial-port

Could anyone tell me how to format the serialport.write method in c# for the following get memory command of a digital multimeter?

DLE
 STX
 Command
 arg1
 arg2
 arg3
 DLE
 ETX

10h
 02h
 4Eh
 00h
 00h
 00h
 10h
 03h

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating a byte array, and writing this to the port.

```
byte[] data = new byte[] {0x10, 0x02, 0x4E, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x10, 0x03};

port.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
```